# react-redux + reselect + immutable.js call to many connects (performance)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

Not so long ago, I started working with react, and I have a performance problem.

I use react + redux + reselect + immutable.js. I have a lot data (like big table with data ~10mb).

My problem is: when I have ~10 000 rows, react creates 10 000 components with: individual `connect`, `memoize selector`.

1 row consist of ~50 keys (from different stores, for ex: col height, focus index), arrays and etc. For example key `title`.

When I modify store, for example change `title` in row #123, redux will execute 10 000 `memoize selectors`, compare results and it take ~1-2 sec for 10k rows!

How I can prevent `connect` calls when I know which component must exactly be re-rendered? Like signal "component with id: `row-123` must run `memoize selector` and check changes" or any ideas?

I plan to try mobx but I don't actually sure that mobx will prevent unnecessary data comparing for every of 10k component.

P.S. I already thought about pagination, virtual scrolling, but I need to display all the data at the same time into the DOM

Comment: do you really want to draw 10k component ? maybe use pagination ?

Comment: @FrançoisRichard I dont wont, but I have to :) I already thought about pagination, virtual scrolling, but I need to display all the data at the same time in DOM :(

Comment: why do you need this ? who can read 10k line at the same time ? :/

Comment: @FrançoisRichard a lot of reasons. for ex: 1) for calculating summary scroll height (any row can consist custom height, images with height. 2) Searching by F3 3) DragNDrop from button of table to head of table. 4) Multi-select functionality, for selecting by moving cursor ... x) etc... p.s. Browser can do it and works FAST with DOM. It means that I am limited only by redux

Comment: @MixerOID you can implement all those features using pagination. It would be MUCH better. For search you can add custom search component and assign its focus for F3 or just leave as it is - it wouldn't hurt

Comment: @VasylButov nope. For ex real scroll height for "whole content" will not work. I cant calculate it without drawing each row.

Comment: point 1. is irrelevant (you need 10k to calculate 10k height) , point 2. can (should ?) be done server side with pagination, point 3, use pagination + some filters feature, point 4. same, you'll use filter nobody will scroll 10k for multiselect ;;;; just my opinion though

Comment: @FrançoisRichard Okay. I heard. But the task sounds completely different :(

Comment: @MixerOID do you use Immutable.js? It could be your answer

Comment: @VasylButov yes. Without immutable.js situation much worse.

Comment: sounds different task yes, but 10k row in a browser, maybe it's better your app just being a way to download a spreadsheet, excel/libreoffice could do 10k row easily

Answer (score 0):

As long as your app **state is updated**, each connected component will **compare new and old state and properties** (one by one) to understand whether a new component render is needed.

This operation is also supposed to **trigger the selectors** used to derive connected components' properties.

Redux's `connect` API exposes the possibility of customising the pre-rendering checks providing an [options object](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#options-object) with the following custom checks:

- `areStatesEqual`
- `areOwnPropsEqual`
- `areStatePropsEqual`
- `areMergedPropsEqual`

Comment: My question is: how to prevent `each connected component will compare new and old state and properties (one by one)` in some cases. Prevent calling all connects

Answer (score -2):

I really wanted to comment but I cant, sorry for that. But I think "react-virtualized" can be what you are looking for

https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List

Comment: > P.S. I already thought about pagination, `virtual scrolling` ... I've already tried `react-virtualized`

Comment: Yes, I've read your statement. But i think your all requirements could be covered with virtual scrolling. Where do you exactly face a problem while trying react-virtualized?